# Risks of sync_binlog = 0 for mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, binlog

I'm trying to understand the risks of `sync_binlog=0` for MySQL. We do not have a slave database, and, if we lost a second or two's (or even a minute or twos) transactions in the case of a catastrophic failure it wouldn't be the end of the world. In which case, is it safe/preferable to put on `sync_binlog=0`? It seems like it can roughly double performance / write access which seems like a win.

I guess my question is: If in the case of a failure and you have `sync_binlog=0`, are you guaranteed that the worst that would happen is a few seconds of data loss? Or, it is possible that the database would be stuffed and you'd have to restore from a backup?

Comment: What kind of storage do you use? This parameter should not have a big impact in the case of DC SSDs.

Comment: We're on linode, and I believe we're using SSD's. I'm unsure if I'm going to make this change, but, we have seen a bunch of `InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took XXX ms` errors. I have tried increasing the io_capactity, decreasing the `innodb_lru_scan_depth` but still have these periodic slowdowns. I was thinking to test disable the binlog to see if it made a difference, but, I wanted to understand the risks first.

Comment: For the page cleaner loop, you might like to read my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134785/how-to-solve-mysql-warning-innodb-page-cleaner-1000ms-intended-loop-took-xxx/41155396#41155396 and also read the comments, there's some interesting discusion. Increasing `innodb_io_capacity` can make that issue worse, not better.

Comment: Hi @BillKarwin - yip, your post was excellent and it's most of the things I have tried. We are on SSD's and I only increased the `innodb_io_capacity` from 200 to 400. It didn't have any noticeable affect either way. I had seen that note about it potentially making things worse :+1:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_sync_binlog says:

> `sync_binlog=0`: Disables synchronization of the binary log to disk by the MySQL server. Instead, the MySQL server relies on the operating system to flush the binary log to disk from time to time as it does for any other file. This setting provides the best performance, but in the event of a power failure or operating system crash, it is possible that the server has committed transactions that have not been synchronized to the binary log.

When MySQL writes to the binary log, it writes using buffered I/O supported by the operating system. The OS is responsible for flushing I/O requests to the physical storage. It usually does this pretty promptly. You're not guaranteed a worst-case disaster. If you have a fairly moderate rate of writes, the OS might flush buffered I/O nearly as quickly as the writes are happening. So odds are when a crash happens, all the pending writes have already been flushed anyway, so you lose nothing.

But if there is a lot of concurrent I/O activity competing for the storage device, or if your database writes are continual and at a high rate, it's more likely that the I/O buffer has a non-trivial amount of content pending flush to disk. That's the portion that would be lost in a crash.

If your system can tolerate some data loss under rare conditions, you might decide to relax durability settings like `sync_binlog`. This will help reduce overhead when you COMMIT transactions.

If you have no replicas and you want to reduce overhead even more, you could consider disabling the binary log. Then you don't worry about the durability of using `sync_binlog`, since it won't be making writes at all.

But replication is not the only purpose of the binary log. It can be used for point-in-time recovery, or for changelog streaming (using tools like Debezium), or for inspecting the history of changes (though an audit log is better for this).

Comment: Thanks Bill, I think yes, we can definitely tolerate some data loss in rare conditions. It's probably worth experimenting with and seeing if we do notice any kind of improvement, possibly the issue lies somewhere else (most likely a noisy neighbour). My thought is that we do have a noisy neighbour and so if we can tolerate the changes being buffered in memory the odd time that this _might_ help. Worth a try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following happens when the Primary crashes without flushing the binlog.

The Primary does two things when it "sends" data to the Replica(s):  (1) send across the network and (2) append to the binlog.

However, if the append did not happen because of the Primary crashed, the Replica will think that the next location to read from in the binlog is somewhere off the end of that binlog file.

This can cause replication to stop with an error message something like "... impossible position ...".  The fix is to do a `CHANGE MASTER ...`  to point the Replica at position 0 (or 4) of the *next* binlog.  Until you do this, no replication is flowing to that Replica.  At that point, most (or maybe all) of the un-replicated writes are sent to that Replica.

You can consider this "worse" or just a "nuisance".